# How to filter Custom Sharepoint Search Refinement Panel Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

I try to develop a custom refinement panel for fast search for sharepoint 2010.

Let's say, when a checkbox's value changed, new querystring formed and submitted.

I mean, how to add r="parameter" to the querystring programmatically.
This is an url example : http://intranet.contoso.com/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=contoso&r=author%3D%22**AQ5TeXN0ZW0gQWNjb3VudAZhdXRob3IBAl4iAiIk**%22
as you can see, "parameter" value is decoded to the bolded part.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should answer your question

http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-refinement-query-parameter-for.html

Comment: In fact, I check Mikael's blog daily, how I missed this entry. Thanks.